# Can i avoid triggering a property watcher when i need it to not trigger?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a method on `created()` that checks if you have previously used some custom values in the data filters on the page. If there are any saved, then i will use those, and set my filter properties to those saved values. This means as soon as you load the page, you will be seeing the data filtered by the criteria you used on your last visit.

This also means that i have watchers on those properties, so that each time you change a data filter, the filters get saved to your account preferences.

The problem currently, is that my `created()` method, in case you did have previously saved filters, will trigger changes on the 5 different filters when it restores them, thus triggering the filters to be saved 5 times as soon as you open the page.

I don't know how to avoid this... I can minimize it a little bit by checking if `newValue !== oldValue` for the off-chance that the value you used is the default value, but still for people who use all 5 filters different than the default values, it will trigger a 5-time save, that's the worst-case scenario.

Sample excerpt of the relevant code to illustrate the point:

```
    created() {
        let savedFilters = this.loadSelectedFilters();
        if(savedFilters) {
            this.selected.filter1 = savedFilters.filter1;
            this.selected.filter2 = savedFilters.filter2;
            this.selected.filter3 = savedFilters.filter3;
            this.selected.filter4 = savedFilters.filter4;
            this.selected.filter5 = savedFilters.filter5;
        }
    },

    watch: {
        'selected.filter1': function(value, oldValue) {
            if(value !== oldValue) {
                this.storeSelectedFilters();
            }
        },
        'selected.filter2': function(value, oldValue) {
            if(value !== oldValue) {
                this.storeSelectedFilters();
            }
        },
        'selected.filter3': function(value, oldValue) {
            if(value !== oldValue) {
                this.storeSelectedFilters();
            }
        },
        'selected.filter4': function(value, oldValue) {
            if(value !== oldValue) {
                this.storeSelectedFilters();
            }
        },
        'selected.filter5': function(value, oldValue) {
            if(value !== oldValue) {
                this.storeSelectedFilters();
            }
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to defer creating the watchers until after you've loaded the saved values:

```js
created() {
  const savedFilters = this.loadSelectedFilters();

  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
    const filter = `filter${i}`;

    if (savedFilters) {
      this.selected[filter] = savedFilters[filter];
    }

    this.$watch('selected.${filter}', () => {
      this.storeSelectedFilters();
    });
  }
},
```

Assuming `loadSelectedFilters` is not asynchronous, which it doesn't appear to be in the example you've given, another alternative might be to set the initial values inside the `data` function, rather than inside `created`. A bit like this:

```js
data() {
  const savedFilters = this.loadSelectedFilters();

  return {
    selected: {
      filter1: savedFilters ? savedFilters.filter1 : 'default',
      // ... other filters
    }
  };
}
```